# jshint error in ember component

Tags: ember.js, jshint

I am using ember-cli-auto-complete in an ember component I defined. In my AutoComplete.extend() I used in KeyCodes and HIDDEN conts, which are defined in the ember-cli-auto-complete/components/auto-complete. The code works but jshint gives me error:

'HIDDEN' is not defined.

'KeyCodes' is not defined.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: If you update your .jshintrc file with "predef:" ["HIDDEEN", "KeyCodes"] you won't get those errors anymore.

Comment: How do I import KeyCode, I tried `import KeyCodes from     "ember-cli-auto-complete/components/utilities/key-codes";`

Comment: You don't import them you go into your [.jshintrc](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/.jshintrc) file that should be present at the root of your app's directory and you add `HIDDEN` and `KeyCodes` to the predef object, once that is done restart your server.